# Run web sockets from Android web server?

Tags: android, webserver, websocket

I would like to run a web server on an Android, and serve web sockets from it. Is that possible?
What tools would I use? Would [iJetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/) work?

Answer (score 3):

try i-jetty!
Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

Answer (score 0):

One other important consideration when running a web server, is Android kills services periodically. Depending on system needs your service / i-jetty or any other service really can be killed by OS. So web server might be down when you need it serving requests.